# Is React super(props) deprecated?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-class-based-component

I've always used something similar to

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        
        this.state = {
            var1 : undefined,
            var2 : 'etc...',
        }
    }
}
```

But today I noticed while working in VS Code there is a strike-thru line on `super(props)`, which was never there before !?

[image]
What has changed? (the link to the docs in the popup is not very helpful)

Comment: This is the second SO post I've seen today for this exact issue. Google search: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40511 Looks to be issue with the typescript vscode uses for linting. Vscode in their August 2020 update (from just a few days ago) updated to typescript 4.0 https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_typescript-40. It has the smell of all being related.

Comment: What did the React docs say about this when you looked there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like a bug. Please see  - [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127040036/https://www.blog4js.com/2020/10/07/why-is-super-deprecated-in-a-react-class-component/) for explanation and there is a link to a source.

Comment: Link only answers aren't much helpful. Next time, along with the link, include a snippet from that linked page.

Also, that link now redirects to a spam ad site.

Answer (score 18):

My guess is that your editor is showing you the description for the super(props, context) signature which *is* deprecated. That link it's pointing to is all about how the old context API is going away, and that particular call signature is part of what is leaving.

However, I haven't heard of a plain `super(props)` going away, you should be safe to continue using that.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a super(props,context) signature, therefore I've never used it. But VS Code (or whatever linter they are using) is causing just a normal `super(props)`  to be flagged. I'll probably ignore it for now, until someone fixes it on their side.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a bug.
If you update your "@types/react" it will solve the problem.

```
npm install --dev @types/react
```

when you your code on the @latest

```
npm install --also=dev @types/react
```

Answer (score 0):

**super(props)** is not been deprecated. See the official doc - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

This is not an error actually. This is a bug related to the code editor, Typescript and React. You can read here - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40511

The good news is *this is resolved*. You can find the solution here - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/47784

Answer (score -5):

### Use just super() instead of super(props)

**super(props)** :

- By using this, we can access and use ***this.props*** object in the constructor.

**super()** :

- If you are not using ***this.props*** in the constructor there is no need to pass ***props*** to the super().
- Instead of ***this.props***, you can always use ***props***.
- It’s okay to not pass ***props*** to super as irrespective of passing it to super, ***this.props*** is still available inside render function.

  ```
  class MyComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super();

          this.state = {
               var1 : undefined,
               var2 : 'etc...',
          };
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: This just creates an error instead for those with type-checking turned on, as there currently isn't a zero-param overload for the constructor in the React types.